# syntax error with a regex in unix

Tags: regex, linux, unix, ubuntu, grep

I tried find a regular expression that matches any number between 1 and 999.
When is uses hooks I get a syntax error

```
(bash: syntax error near unexpected token `(')
```

and when I don't use the hooks nothing happens.

my regex is:

```
egrep ^([1-9][0-9]?|)$ Numbers
```

update:

but how can i get him to check the file i want him to check, because know i can check the numbers if i use  echo but i should check the file

Comment: You don't need the pipe `|` unless your doing a conditional.

Answer (score 2):

This should match any number between 1 and 999.  I added the `{0,2}` which means match between 0 and 2 repeats of the [0-9] character group.

```
 ^[1-9][0-9]{0,2}$
```

If you are trying to match the parenthesis and pipe character, then you'll need to escape them:

```
 ^\([1-9][0-9]{0,2}\|\)$
```

Answer (score 0):

Enclose the regex in double-quotes or escape the parantheses and pipes with backslash.

e.g. `egrep "^([1-9][0-9]?|)$"` or `egrep ^\([1-9][0-9]?\|\)$`.

BTW, your regex seems to be broken. How about `egrep "^[1-9][0-9]?[0-9]?$"`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
echo $number | grep '^[1-9][0-9]\{0,2\}$'
```

Comment: but how can i get him to check the file i want him to check, because know i can check the numbers i echo but i should check the file

Comment: @Bjorn: `grep '^[1-9][0-9]\{0,2\}$' filename` should do the trick.