# create a regex to match numbers between 1 - 999 in a file

Tags: regex, linux, unix, ubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [syntax error with a regex in unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831555/syntax-error-with-a-regex-in-unix)

i tried to create a regex to match numbers between 1 - 999, but i can get it just right can annybody help me, mine current regex is egrep ^ ([1-9][0-9]{0,2})$ Numbers, but now it doesn't makr anny

Comment: This regex will accept 1 or 001 to 999: ^(0{0,2}[1-9]|0?[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9])$

Answer (score 3):

Your regexp would work but only if there are no other characters before or after the number 1-999. By the way there seems to be a space character between ^ and the first parenthesis; that might be what is causing the problem. Another problem is that you need to quote the regexp to prevent the shell from interpreting the special characters like $, [, ], etc.

The correct command is 
 **egrep '^([1-9][0-9]{0,2})$'**